# Can you use the word "where" in a sentence this way?

Tags: grammar, sentence

Is it proper grammar to use the word "where" after a comma, or can I replace this word with something more appropriate?

*"I was employed as a **______** at ABC Company, **where I was responsible** for managing a team of 20 employees."*

Answer (score 2):

It indeed sounds perfectly alright.

That said, you could also say:

*"I was employed as a **______** at ABC Company. **My job consisted in** 
managing a team of 20 employees."*

Comment: You can also say "consisted *of*".

Comment: @MrHen Sure. My hotel room consisted of a king bed, sitting room, bath with hot tub and walkin shower, and a dramatic view over the meandering Dordogne River. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is grammatically correct. You can substitute *where* with *in which*

Comment: To my ears, that would sound unnatural in this sentence.

Answer (score 1):

'Where' sounds perfectly alright if you want to draw attention to your entire time spent at the ABC company. But if you want the details in the second part of the sentence to explain the actual job mentioned in the first part, then it might be better to use 'in which capacity'.  So the sentence reads:

*I was employed as a project manager at the ABC company, in which capacity I was responsible for managing a team of 20 employees.*

Comment: I see. Does "in which capacity" apply if I were to write my sentence in the present tense? I have spent a year at my current job and I'm still employed there so I don't know if I should use present or past tense on top of all things.

Comment: @Helium87 You would change the conjugation of the verb *to be* from *was* to *am*. E.g., "...where I **am** responsible for...".